# Dropdownlist display issues in IE 10

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-10

I am running a .net web application on IE10. The issue seems to be with the way the items are being displayed in the dropdownlist. In IE10 if an item is chosen from the list which happens to be in middle (say you are choosing the 3rd item out of 5) and then again click on drop down list then the list spans as 2 elements above this value and 2 below. Also if you choose the very last item and then again click on the drop down the list is displayed as all the items above the last item and then the last item in the field (list is displayed upwards).

So the issue appears when these items are displayed after choosing them and clicking again on the control just to see all the items.

In IE8 and 9 it is like the item chosen is displayed in the field
and then the whole list follows below this.

Please help...

Comment: Can you post a link to an example of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also meet this problem.
But when I search [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/740fd6f1-50a2-4fd8-bd94-563c620a4201/), it is said be design. I don't know if it is true, but I couldn't find anyway to fix it.